# Classic ASP XMLHttp Send very slow

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest, timing

I've inherited a classic asp project and as part of the upgrade process we're moving a lot of the business logic to a REST API (WebApi 2.2)

The authorization endpoint for the api is written, and the asp site can call it, but it's very slow compared with calling directly via Postman.

(I'm a C# coder not a VBScript one so the below code may be offensive)

Asp Code:

```
' Send a prebuilt HTTP request and handle the response
' Returns true if the request returns a 200 response, False otherwise 
' Response body is placed in Response
' ErrorMessage is set to return status text if an error code is returned  

Function HandleRequest(ByRef objRequest, strBody)
    set profiler = Server.CreateObject("Softwing.Profiler")
    HandleRequest = False

    ' Add auth token if we have it
    If Not m_accessToken&"" = "" Then
        objRequest.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & m_accessToken 
    End If

    ' Originating IP for proxy forwarding
    If Not m_clientIp&"" = "" Then
        objRequest.SetRequestHeader "X-Forwarded-For", m_clientIp
    End If

    On Error Resume Next


    If (strBody&"" = "") Then
        objRequest.Send()
    Else
        profiler.ProfileStart()
        objRequest.Send(strBody)
        flSendRequest = profiler.ProfileStop()
    End If


    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Dim jsonResponse

        If (objRequest.ResponseText&"" <> "") Then
            profiler.ProfileStart()
            set jsonResponse = JSON.parse(objRequest.ResponseText)
            flJson = profiler.ProfileStop()
            set m_Response = jsonResponse
        End If

        If objRequest.Status = 200 Then
            HandleRequest = True
            m_errorMessage = ""
        Else
            m_errorMessage = objRequest.statusText
        End If
    Else
        m_errorMessage = "Unable to connect to Api server"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

You can see there's some profiling code in there.

The following post request takes 392ms

```
POST localhost:5000/oauth/token
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id:ABCDEF0-ABCD-ABCD-ABCD-ABCDEF-ABCDEF01234
client_secret:aBcDeF0123456789aBcDeF0123456789=
username:demo
password:demo
grant_type:password
```

If I issue the same request direct to the Api via Postman it takes 30ms.

That's more than 13x slower.

What gives?

**Edit**

Raw result from Softwing Profiler:

```
flJson          10.9583865754112    
flSendRequest   392.282022557137
```

Comment: Are you issuing the request from the same machine each time or does the ASP code reside somewhere different to Postman? For it to be a valid test you need to run both from the same location. Also bear in mind that the COM profiler will add a small overhead to the code execution. Also doubt that is all the ASP code that runs when you call the ASP page.

Comment: Same machine. Everything is done locally. Also I figured there'd be a profiler overhead but this seems excessive. (The reason for running the profiler in the first place was an obvious speed difference when running normally)

Comment: Do you have the raw timings from the `Softwing.Profiler` for the `objRequest.Send(strBody)` part? Not used the raw profiler before I've always used it wrapped library called [The `SlTiming` Class Library](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/020302-1.shtml) which allows you more control over the timings and producing a summary.

Comment: Added them in the edit above. I paused for a while as the SlTiming library says that Softwing's timings are in tenths of a ms (so perhaps I've just forgotten to divide by 10). But their [own help](http://www.alphasierrapapa.com/IisDev/Components/Profiler/) says that timings are in ms.

Comment: Like I say I've never used the raw `Softwing.Profiler` it's always been in conjunction with the `SLTiming` library and it's never steered me wrong.

Comment: I'll check it out. Maybe it's correct and the help is wrong. In which case my performance issue is elsewhere. (although if that's the case then that json parse is *really* fast.) Cheers.

Comment: Don't think the help is wrong. Although the 4guysfromrolla article does state *"tenths of milliseconds"* it's referring to the resolution of the timer as stated in softwings documentation - *"has a ten milliseconds resolution"*. The value returned by `ProfileStop()` is in milliseconds though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125491/discussion-between-j-tolley-and-lankymart).

Comment: So to clarify `SlTiming` is right but `Softwing.Profiler` is wrong. If you use `.ProfileStop()` remember the value returned is in ticks *(tenths of a millisecond)*. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a [lengthy-ish discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125491/discussion-between-j-tolley-and-lankymart) with the [@J-Tolley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249813/j-tolley) it looks as though the issue is with the [`Softwing.Profiler` documentation](http://www.alphasierrapapa.com/IisDev/Components/Profiler/) which states;

> *all results are given in milliseconds*

even though earlier in the page it states;

> *has a ten milliseconds resolution*

Have not used the `Softwing.Profiler` component alone before and would recommend anyone using in a Classic ASP environment to implement it using the [`SlTiming` class library](https://web.archive.org/web/20100302021042/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/webtech/code/SlTiming.inc.html) provided by [4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020135223/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/020302-1.shtml).

In [that article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020135223/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/020302-1.shtml) it even warns anyone using the `Softwing.Profiler` `ProfileStop()` method to;

> *Be aware that Softwing.Profiler's `ProfileStop` method returns a value in ticks (**tenths of milliseconds**)*.